# passing multiple informations in anonymous object using razor helper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

If I'm already assigning value using anonymous object inside html element using razor helper

```
@Html.ReadOnlyTextBox(MyObject.SomeId.ToString(), MyObject.PersonName.ToString(), true, new { @class = field.IsWarned ? "myCssClassName" : string.Empty })
```

now I want to extend this above code

```
var someVar = true;
if(a>b){
   someVar = false;
}
```

how can I inject also value of someVar together with @class (in both cases)

Comment: samovar is another route parameter to be passed or require only to apply the appropriate class?

Comment: it's not route parameter, I want to sent as another property, can be another class though

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the parameter to html attributes you can pass it as another parameter

```
Html.ReadOnlyTextBox(MyObject.SomeId.ToString(), MyObject.PersonName.ToString(), true, new { @class = (field.IsWarned ? "myCssClassName" : string.Empty), @someVar = (a > b ? false: true) })
```

Comment: Why not just `@someVar = a <= b`?

Comment: Yes, that can be done. Initially posted like that but later changed to for more readability.

Comment: great, how can I extend this to use data- attribute, like data-myVar instead of @someVar?

Comment: define it like as data_someVar. If you notice, underscore (_) is used instead of dash (-) as if you try using dash then framework will not treat as attribute and will not generate data attribute